# Image getting out of container

Tags: css, post-thumbnails

[image]

In my index page, I use the featured image next to the post excerpt.

```
    .alignleft {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1.5em;}
   .wp-post-image {
        margin-left: 1em;
        width: 120px;
        height: 90px;}
```

Although it is contained within the article (.hentry)

```
    <article id="post-1727" class="post-1727 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized">

<header class="entry-header">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2015/10/08/image-on-post/" rel="bookmark">Image on post</a></h2>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <a href="http://xxx" title="Image on post" class="alignleft">
                <img src="http://xxx" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="dsc20040724_152504_532" height="480" width="640">        </a>
        <!-- post thumbnail -->

        <div class="entry-summary">
            <p> text here</p>

                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    .hentry {
        margin: 0px 0px 0.5em;
        padding: 5px 0px 0em 0.4em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

I can not prevent it from getting out of the article border. I have tried to adjust the margin but it didn't help much. How can I prevent the image of getting out of the article area?

PS: I know this could be considered a general css question. I asked it here because it has to do with the featured image feature of wordpress.

Comment: it's still a css question which is better off being asked on stackoverflow, this site is for WP questions... but to guide you in the right direction, give the image a max-width of 100% ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `hentry` CSS and add overflow to hidden. Like this.

```
.hentry {
    margin: 0px 0px 0.5em;
    padding: 5px 0px 0em 0.4em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

This will fix the issue of image being getting outside of the article container.